# How do I relocate Colonists?

Tags: star-trek-online

I have a full passenger list and frequently acquire an excess of colonial passengers through repeating the Resettle Colonists duty officer mission (it gives my duty officers something to do when my In Progress total is lower than 20). However, while the Resettle mission reappears constantly, colonization assignment chain missions have not appeared at all since I began playing again a few weeks ago, and I check in every few hours to see how my duty officers are doing.

My specific focus right now is on the "Colonization of the Arucanis Arm" assignment chain, so I have tried hanging out in the Celes Sector Block and inside the Arucanis Arm itself, both for extended periods of time so that I would not miss an update of the mission list by switching from one to the other too quickly.

Investigating the STO [wiki](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Assignment:_Relocate_Colonists) on gamepedia.com, I did not learn any specific details that help my understanding of the situation.

Are there any triggers that cause the colonization assignment chain mission to appear in the Duty Officer mission list? Or, are there any triggers that cause the mission to *not* show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from dismissing them the [assignment Relocate Colonists](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Assignment:_Relocate_Colonists) is the only way to remove passengers from your roster (at least on the federation side, as a Klingon you can and have to sell them as slaves as well). The assignment usually appears once a day in the space area around major stations, like Earth Space Dock and Deep Space 9 as well as in all colonization locaions (Expanses, Star clusters etc.).

I'm not quite sure if the "once per day" is triggered by location or by character ... it is quite possible that you can only run the assignment once per day, regardless where you picked it up.

And of course, if you have filtered the list of assignments to only show assignments with the required resources available, you have to make sure you have enough medical supplies and provisions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to physically visit each of the various expanses to see the Duty Officer assignments available there. There are, I think, 7 such locations on the main map and they pretty reliable have the repeatable "additional Colonists" assignments available once you have progressed sufficiently through the assignment sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the 2 answers given (Doff missions), there are a some fleet projects that take common civilians as inputs.  The best one is the special project "Coordinate Colonization Efforts" project in the Starbase area.  Doing this can net you some good fleet credits.

Another option is to sell colonists on the exchange.  Which sounds odd for the Federation, but it's totally permitted.  People looking to do the colony assignment chains would be happy to buy them.